# percent problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A recipe of trail mix has 3 ingredients wich includes 20% raisins,20% m&M's and 60% nuts.if I had a total of 8 cups of trail mix. How much (in cups) do I have of each ingredients?

Comment: This will likely garner downvotes for being an arithmetic question tagged as real-analysis. Arithmetic questions are perfectly valid here, but please consider appropriate tags in the future. See the answer provided by Ross Millikan for a good approach to your problem.

Comment: This is _not_ real analysis.  Please use relevant tags.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:  Can you convert $20\%$ to a decimal?  Can you multiply it by $8$?